# apply filters only to specific post listing without check the url parameters

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization

I have made a custom post type named as: slider, in my plugin class, I am adding a filter 
which calls the method remove_row_action that unsets view links from actions

```
   add_filter('post_row_actions', array(&$this, 'remove_row_actions'), 10, 1);

   public function remove_row_actions($action) {

    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])  && $_GET['post_type'] == 'slider')) {
        unset($action['view']);
        return $action;
    }else{
        return $action;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly well, but I believe there must be a cleaner way in which the add_filter only applies for the custom post type, instead of me checking it by the GET variable

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're right. There is a clever way. post_row_actions filter can accept also second param $post from which you can get it's post_type. See the code:

```
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', array( $this, 'remove_row_actions' ), 10, 2);
public function remove_row_actions( $action, $post ) {
    if ( 'slider' === get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        unset $action['view'];
        return $action;
    }
    return $action;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just inspect the `get_current_screen()` object. It will tell you what you got. The same goes for the `$query` argument that you can find inside the `parse_request` and `pre_get_posts` filters.